# How to filter a table of images

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to filter a table of images using a search bar. I can do it when there is text in the table, but I just want there to be images in the table. Is there a way to get the id or the alt in the form of a string?

```js
function search() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("champions");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getAttribute("alt");
    console.log(td);
    if (td) {
      //alert(td);
      txtValue = td;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

search();
```

```html
Input: <input type="text" id="myInput" />
<br/>
<table id="champions">
  <tr>
    <td><img id="1" onclick="clicked()" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src=".png" alt="1a"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

The search is getting called but when it gets to if(td) it returns null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `alt` attribute you're looking for is an attribute of the `img` tag, but your code is looking for it inside the `td` tag.

You can find that by changing

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getAttribute("alt");
```

to

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("alt");
```

Demo:

```js
function search() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("champions");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("alt");
    console.log(td);
    if (td) {
      //alert(td);
      txtValue = td;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

search();
```

```html
Input: <input type="text" id="myInput" />
<br/>
<table id="champions">
  <tr>
    <td><img id="1" onclick="clicked()" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src=".png" alt="1a"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```